# converting sybase datetime format to oracle timestamp

Tags: oracle, sybase, datetime-format, oracle12c

I am getting bellow datetime format from sybase DB

```
2015-08-12T11:49:50.196+01:00
```

and i need to insert this value into oracle database column of type TIMESTAMP(6).

i am not able to specify the correct format to insert the above datetime in to Timestamp column in oracle.

can any one help me in this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don't want to store time zone information (thus type TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE)?

```
CREATE TABLE timestamp (value TIMESTAMP(6));
INSERT INTO timestamp VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-08-12T11:49:50.196+01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM'));
```